# pass %userprofile% into another batch

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file that writes to another batch file for the purpose of restoring files  later from another system. The `%userprofile%` gets interpreted by the current running batch. So when I check the batch it created it fills in the user that ran it before.

Example:

```
echo XCOPY "%%~dp0User files\Desktop\*.*" "%userprofile%\Desktop\Old Desktop shortcuts" /C /S /Y /I >> "!D!:\Backup-%computername%-%date:~-10,2%-%date:~7,2%-%date:~-4,4%\Restore_User_Files.bat"
```

It creates a Restore_User_files.bat and when I open it up on another system it shows:

```
XCOPY "%%~dp0User files\Desktop\*.*" "C:\Documents and Settings\randomness\Desktop\Old Desktop shortcuts"
```

I want to pass that `%userprofile%` into the batch untouched and not the user name of the system that wrote it so another system can interpret it as `%userprofile%`

Any suggestions? Im sure Im just missing some chars......If I'm not making sense let me know =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Double the percent signs.

```
%%userprofile%%
```

Comment: I think I may have tried that already but I will give it a shot. Thanks for the speedy responses.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to escape the % signs in your command with ^ characters.  In this case, `^%USERPROFILE^%` should do what you want.

Comment: That will not work within a batch file - the percents need to be doubled as in foxidrive's answer. Your solution could work from the command line, but it isn't really escaping the percents. A caret could be placed anywhere between the percents and it would usually work from the command line.

Comment: @Mark Thanks Mark. You can consider removing your answer in SO when you think it has little value, to keep the thread to the point and clearer for future readers.